# Commuting elements in ${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ are powers of some element

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

In free groups, it is easy to show that two commuting elements are powers of some element:

if $x,y$ are in a free group, then $\langle x,y\rangle$ is free, being subgroup of a free group, with rank $1$ or $2$. If it is of rank $2$, then $x,y$ will not commute, a contradiction. Thus, $\langle x,y\rangle$ is free of rank $1$ i.e. cyclic.

In a paper by Lyndon and Morris Newman, the authors say that similar thing happens in ${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$. They say:

> *An easy consequence of the Kurosh subgroup theorem (or of simple matrix calculation) is that two commuting elements of ${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ are 
>   necessarily powers of the same element of ${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$.*

Any hint to prove this? (both by Kurosh theorem and by Matrix multiplication).

Comment: Let $x,y$ be commuting elements in $PSL(2,Z)=Z_2 * Z_3$. By Kurosh theorem, $\langle x,y\rangle$ is decomposed as a free product with components among $\{$ (a free group), (conjugate of subgroup of $Z_2$) and (conjugates of subgroups of $Z_3$) $\}$. Since $<z,y>$ is cyclic, there should be at most one component in above decomposition and it should be cyclic; we arrive at conclusion. Is this correct? (I also want to see how to prove it by matrix calculation?)

Comment: It is an old result (I think of Solitar) that if $g$ is a non-trivial element of a free product with amalgamation $G = A *_H B$ where $H$ is malnormal in $G$, the centralizer of $g$ is either cyclic or it is in a conjugate of a factor. Since in $PSL(2, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_3$ the subgroup $H = \{1\}$, which is trivially malnormal, the result applies.

Comment: Probably, the centralizer of $g$ may be virtually cyclic and not necessarily cyclic. I think an even more general justification comes from Bass-Serre theory, by looking at the action on the associated Bass-Serre tree.